# What does "where T : class, new()" mean?

Tags: c#, generics, type-constraints

Can you please explain to me what `where T : class, new()` means in the following line of code?

```
void Add<T>(T item) where T : class, new();
```

Comment: for later use: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does new() mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236854/what-does-new-mean)

Answer (score 431, accepted):

That is a constraint on the generic parameter `T`. It must be a `class` (reference type) and must have a public parameter-less default constructor.

That means `T` can't be an `int`, `float`, `double`, `DateTime` or any other `struct` (value type).

It could be a `string`, or any other custom reference type, as long as it has a default or parameter-less constructor.

Comment: Just to clarify, if you don't have the class clause as part of the where T..., then it is safe to use int, float, double etc.

Comment: @AboutDev correct, you don't have to put constraints on your generic type parameter. But if you are creating a generic that expects to only work on reference or value types, then you should specify. Without a constraint, you can expect reference types (classes) or value types (structs (int, float, double...)).

Comment: What about where T : [interface name], new() ? Do you still need to have a parameter-less constructor?

Comment: To clarify Justin's comment, an empty constructor has no statements (like the default constructor) while a parameterless constructor may contain statements (like initializing a list).

Comment: @VinceTino: `new()` precisely specifies "must have a public parameterless constructor"

Comment: To my greatest surprise, `new()` also excludes constructors with a single parameter and default value for it... I find this unintuitive, at least.

Answer (score 222):

Those are generic type constraints. In your case there are two of them:

```
where T : class
```

Means that the type `T` must be a reference type (not a value type).

```
where T : new()
```

Means that the type `T` must have a parameter-less constructor. Having this constraint will allow you to do something like `T field = new T();` in your code which you wouldn't be able to do otherwise.

You then combine the two using a comma to get:

```
where T : class, new()
```

Comment: Good points for second and third, just to add information, I think second point is useful when doing reflection in generic type. eg. T t = new T(); t.GetType().GetProperty("ID").SetValue(t, uniqueId, null);

Comment: I believe it is redundant to say where T : class, new(), since new() already implies class because structs cannot have default constructors.

Comment: @DharmaTurtle, "structs can't contain explicit parameterless constructors", doesn't mean that they don't have one, it says that you can't define one. source : https://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/aa288208(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 162):

**where T : struct**

The type argument must be a value type. Any value type except Nullable can be specified. See Using Nullable Types (C# Programming Guide) for more information.

**where T : class**

The type argument must be a reference type, including any class, interface, delegate, or array type. (See note below.)

**where T : new()**
The type argument must have a public parameterless constructor. When used in conjunction with other constraints, the new() constraint must be specified last.

**where T : [base class name]**

The type argument must be or derive from the specified base class.

**where T : [interface name]**

The type argument must be or implement the specified interface. Multiple interface constraints can be specified. The constraining interface can also be generic.

**where T : U**

The type argument supplied for T must be or derive from the argument supplied for U. This is called a naked type constraint.

(Original Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters)

Comment: This was useful, but [link to source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).

Answer (score 37):

`class` & `new` are 2 [constraints on the generic type parameter `T`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters).
Respectively they ensure:

#### `class`

> The type argument must be a reference type; this applies also to any class, interface, delegate, or array type.

#### `new`

> The type argument must have a public parameterless constructor. When used together with other constraints, the new() constraint must be specified last.

Their combination means that the type `T` must be a [Reference Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) (can't be a [Value Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types)), and must have a parameterless constructor.

Example:

```
struct MyStruct { } // structs are value types

class MyClass1 { } // no constructors defined, so the class implicitly has a parameterless one

class MyClass2 // parameterless constructor explicitly defined
{
    public MyClass2() { }
}

class MyClass3 // only non-parameterless constructor defined
{
    public MyClass3(object parameter) { }
}

class MyClass4 // both parameterless & non-parameterless constructors defined
{
    public MyClass4() { }
    public MyClass4(object parameter) { }
}

interface INewable<T>
    where T : new()
{
}

interface INewableReference<T>
    where T : class, new()
{
}

class Checks
{
    INewable<int> cn1; // ALLOWED: has parameterless ctor
    INewable<string> n2; // NOT ALLOWED: no parameterless ctor
    INewable<MyStruct> n3; // ALLOWED: has parameterless ctor
    INewable<MyClass1> n4; // ALLOWED: has parameterless ctor
    INewable<MyClass2> n5; // ALLOWED: has parameterless ctor
    INewable<MyClass3> n6; // NOT ALLOWED: no parameterless ctor
    INewable<MyClass4> n7; // ALLOWED: has parameterless ctor

    INewableReference<int> nr1; // NOT ALLOWED: not a reference type
    INewableReference<string> nr2; // NOT ALLOWED: no parameterless ctor
    INewableReference<MyStruct> nr3; // NOT ALLOWED: not a reference type
    INewableReference<MyClass1> nr4; // ALLOWED: has parameterless ctor
    INewableReference<MyClass2> nr5; // ALLOWED: has parameterless ctor
    INewableReference<MyClass3> nr6; // NOT ALLOWED: no parameterless ctor
    INewableReference<MyClass4> nr7; // ALLOWED: has parameterless ctor
}
```

Comment: Good Demonstration. Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

**new():** Specifying the new() constraint means type T must use a parameterless constructor, so an object can be instantiated from it - see [Default constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645608(v=vs.71).aspx).

**class:** Means T must be a reference type so it can't be an int, float, double, DateTime or other struct (value type).

```
public void MakeCars()
{
    //This won't compile as researchEngine doesn't have a public constructor and so can't be instantiated.
    CarFactory<ResearchEngine> researchLine = new CarFactory<ResearchEngine>();
    var researchEngine = researchLine.MakeEngine();

    //Can instantiate new object of class with default public constructor
    CarFactory<ProductionEngine> productionLine = new CarFactory<ProductionEngine>();
    var productionEngine = productionLine.MakeEngine();
}

public class ProductionEngine { }
public class ResearchEngine
{
    private ResearchEngine() { }
}

public class CarFactory<TEngine> where TEngine : class, new()
{
    public TEngine MakeEngine()
    {
        return new TEngine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

That means that type `T` must be a class *and* have a constructor that does not take any arguments.

For example, you must be able to do this:

```
T t = new T();
```

Comment: not just a constructor, but a constructor that takes no arguments.

Comment: @NerdFury: Thanks. That is an important bit. Corrected.

Answer (score 6):

[where (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b0scde8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> The new() Constraint lets the compiler know that any type argument supplied must have an accessible parameterless--or default-- constructor

So it should be, `T` must be a class, and have an accessible parameterless--or default constructor.

Answer (score 5):

What comes after the "Where" is a constraint on the generic type T you declared, so:

- **class** means that the T should be a class and not a value type or a struct.
- **new()** indicates that the T class should have a public parameter-free default constructor defined.

Answer (score 2):

It's called a 'constraint' on the generic parameter T. It means that T must be a reference type (a class) and that it must have a public default constructor.

Answer (score 1):

This is part of the Generics mechanism, where the where keyword add constraints to what types must implement in order to be used as type parameters.

Answer (score 0):

when using the **class** in constraints it's mean you can only use Reference type, another thing to add is when to use the constraint **new()**, it's must be the last thing you write in the Constraints terms.