# About Generic types with like T

Tags: c#, generics

I wonder what is this? This kind of a generic method I think. It has a part with 'where'. What about that? There is also generic classes I've heard. How can I learn these can you recommend an article?

```
    protected T Item<T>() where T : class
    {
        return GetDataItem() as T ?? default(T);
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737970/what-does-where-t-class-new-mean

Comment: [Read the fine manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).

Comment: MSDN reference to generics http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: yes this a generic method and where is used to constraint the type of parameters you can return from this method

Comment: Hey this is not duplicate! It isn't the same question as mine. The question you showed is similar with only the 'where' part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `where` clause is called a "generic constraint". In that case, `where T: class` dictates that T must be a reference type (i.e., not a `struct`).

More info on generic constraints: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx
And generic classes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f.aspx

**Edit**

In the snippet you provided, the constraint is needed because otherwise the null-coalescing operator (??) wouldn't make sense, since value types (`struct`s) can't be null.

Comment: minor footnote re your last line: `Nullable<T>` (for any `T : struct`) is itself a `struct` and can notionally be `null`

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Isn't it weird that neither `T:struct` nor `T:class` allow `T` to be a Nullable?