# How to create an instance with generics?

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to do something simple: creating an instance with generics. I get an error saying that I cannot create an instance because I do not have the `new` constraint. However, I do have it on my return statement! Any thoughts?

```
public IAction CreateAction<TA, TP>(ActionParamBase param)
            where TA : IAction
            where TP : ActionParamBase
        {
            Ensure.That(param).Is<TP>();

            return new TA { Param = param as TP };
        }
```

Comment: You need to do this: where TA : class, new()

Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737970/what-does-where-t-class-new-mean

Comment: TA is a generic interface.. you can't create an instance of interfaces

Comment: ok guys thanks for your help ! it worked! => where TA : IAction, new()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What it means is having `new` in the constraint of your TA part. See this SO post for reference, then see code below:
[Passing arguments to C# generic new() of templated type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840261/passing-arguments-to-c-sharp-generic-new-of-templated-type)

```
public IAction CreateAction<TA, TP>(ActionParamBase param)
        where TA : IAction, new()
        where TP : ActionParamBase
    {
        Ensure.That(param).Is<TP>();

        return new TA { Param = param as TP };
    }
```

Comment: it's complaining about `TA`, not `TP`

Comment: Yea sorry I typod that when I initially typed it ;)

Answer (score 5):

You have to specify the `new()` constraint on the `TA` type parameter in order to be able to call the constructor:

```
public IAction CreateAction<TA, TP>(ActionParamBase param)
        where TA : IAction
                 , new()
        where TP : ActionParamBase
    {
        ...
    }
```

Only then it knows (and forces) that `TA` has a parameterless constructor.

(Just a small note: it only works for parameterless constructors, not for constructors having arguments. In this case you are fine since you use initializers)