# What's the benefits of using the method which is using "new()" over the one not using "new()" with where clause in the method in c#?

Tags: c#, methods

There are two methods which does the same task. The only difference in them is one has "new()" and other does not have.

The methods are:

**Method 1**:

```
public void Method1<T>(BaseReportContent content) where T : BaseReportContent, new()
{
   //Codes
}
```

**Method 2**:

```
public void Method2<T>(BaseReportContent content) where T : BaseReportContent
{
   //Codes
}
```

What is the benefits of using one over another?

Let me know if more information required to make this question more precise.

Comment: Answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737970/what-does-where-t-class-new-mean?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: It is simply a constraint, which enforces that the generic type T must be a concrete type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `new()` constraint will allow you to create a new `T`. For instance

```
public void Method1<T>(BaseReportContent content) where T : BaseReportContent, new()
{
    var myT = new T();
}
```

<sub>***Note*** : There are caveats</sub>

[new constraint (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint)

> The new constraint specifies that any type argument in a generic class
>   declaration must have a public parameterless constructor. To use the
>   new constraint, the type cannot be abstract.

---

**Additional Resources**

You can find more information on generic constraints here

[Constraints on type parameters (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters)

> Constraints inform the compiler about the capabilities a type argument
>   must have. Without any constraints, the type argument could be any
>   type. The compiler can only assume the members of System.Object, which
>   is the ultimate base class for any .NET type. For more information,
>   see Why use constraints. If client code tries to instantiate your
>   class by using a type that is not allowed by a constraint, the result
>   is a compile-time error. Constraints are specified by using the where
>   contextual keyword. The following table lists the seven types of
>   constraints:

Lastly, if you need to create something that need constructor parameters, you can use

[Activator.CreateInstance Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Creates an instance of the specified type using the constructor that
>   best matches the specified parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The first method uses the [`new` constaint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint), which means you can write:

```
public void Method1<T>(BaseReportContent content) where T : BaseReportContent, new()
{
    var foo = new T();
}
```

The second method does not have this constraint, which means you cannot write such code.