# What does new() mean in this case?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#: What does new() mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236854/c-what-does-new-mean)

I look at definition of Enum.TryParse:

```
public static bool TryParse<TEnum>(string value, out TEnum result) where TEnum : struct, new();
```

and wondering what `new()` means here.

Comment: @Greg: You're right, I should close this one. Thanks to everybody who responded!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its a generic type parameter constraint that means that the type for TEnum has to have a public, parameterless constructor.

See here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Answer (score 1):

it's a constraint to the generic parameter. It means that `TEnum` must have a parameterless public constructor (and allows you to do `new TEnum()`). Checkout [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) for more details and other type of constraints.

Answer (score 1):

It is a generic type constraint that requires that the generic type parameter `TEnum` must support a default constructor (can be newed up without arguments).

Answer (score 1):

It means that the type TEnum must be able to use

var x = new TEnum();

Answer (score 1):

It basically says that you can only use this on types which have a public parameterless constructor, ie: where you can do:

```
var something = new TEnum();
```

This allows you to enforce that you can create the type internally.

For details, see the [C# new Constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

new() as a generic type restriction means that the type used as the generic parameter must have a constructor with the given parameters; here, it must have a parameterless default constructor.