# Inheritance in C#, what does where T: new()  mean?

Tags: c#, new-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does new() mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236854/what-does-new-mean)

Like in title. I wonder what this syntax in the code means. I've find it in some samples but it wasn't explained and I don't really know what it does.

```
public class SomeClass<T> where T: new()  // what does it mean?
```

Can anyone explain that for me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps you mean you saw something along these lines?

```
public class SomeClass<T> where T: new() 
{...}
```

which means that you can only use the generic class with a type T that has a public parameterless constructor. These are called [generic type constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx). I.e., you cannot do this (see [CS0310](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42h7h44y.aspx)):

```
// causes CS0310 because XmlWriter cannot be instantiated with paraless ctor
var someClass = new SomeClass<XmlWriter>();

// causes same compile error for same reason
var someClass = new SomeClass<string>();
```

Why would you need such constraint? Suppose you want to instantiate the a new variable of type `T`. You can only do that when you have this constraint, otherwise, the compiler cannot know beforehand whether the instantiation works. I.e.:

```
public class SomeClass<T> where T: new() 
{
    public static T CreateNewT()
    {
         // you can only write "new T()" when you also have "where T: new()"
         return new T();
    }
}
```

Comment: thats the answer :) thanks a lot :) now everythink clear:)

Comment: `new SomeClass<string>()` causes an error (it doesn't “throw”), simply because `string` has no parameterless constructor.

Comment: @svick: that's precisely what I meant, I'll remove "throws". CS0310 is a compile time error. The cause was already in my text, I thought.

Comment: @Abel, I thought it confused you, because I read “also throws for **some** reason”. Now I noticed that's not what you wrote, my bad.

Answer (score 3):

It is a [generic type constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx), meaning the generic type must have a public parameterless constructor.

Your code example will not even compile.

The correct syntax is:

```
SomeClass<T> where T : new()
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted the full line of code since that won't compile, but it is a constraint in generics.  [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is the MSDN article.