# What does "T : new()" mean with generics?

Tags: c#, generics

i want to understand that code. I think `T` must be `IContinentFactory's` implemented class but i don't understand to end of  the `new()` keyword.

```
class AnimalWorld<T> : IAnimalWorld where T : IContinentFactory, new()
{
.....
}
```

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: (There is no generic interface here and the other interfaces are just noise around the real question.)

Comment: As a subtlety to consider with the answers given: `struct`s also satisfy the `new()` constraint. It is an interesting question as to whether `struct`s actually have a public parameterless constructor - and IIRC the C# and CLI specifications disagree on this question: but crucially: `struct`s always satisfy this constraint.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does new() mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236854/what-does-new-mean)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`new()` mean that `T` must have default(parameterless) ctor.

**[Constraints on Type Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)**

Answer (score 6):

`T: new()` means that type T has to have a parameter-less constructor.

By that you actually specify that you can write `T param = new T();` in your implementation of `AnimalWorld<T>`

Comment: +1 Only answer to mention that the constraint allows code which uses `T` to do something it otherwise could not.

Answer (score 4):

The constraint `new()` means that the type `T` must have a public parameterless instance constructor. This includes all value types, but not all classes. No interface or delegate type can have such a constructor. When the `new()` constraint is present, `T` can never be an abstract class.

When `new()` is present, the following code is allowed inside the class:

```
T instance = new T();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
class AnimalWorld<T> : IAnimalWorld where T : IContinentFactory, new()
```

Here is what the declaration means:

- `AnimalWorld` is a `class` with a generic type parameter `T`
- The class `AnimalWorld` must implement `IAnimalWorld`
- The type parameter `T` must implement `IContinentFactory`
- The class for the type parameter `T` must have a no-argument constructor (that's what the `new` is for).